# Accessing control values in the Page_Init event in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, page-lifecycle

I am creating a grid programatically in my code-behind and it must be created in the Page_Init event since I am programtically adding GridTemplateColumns to the grid.

The problem is that the creation of the grid relies on the value of an ASP.NET DropDownList control that the user first selects when they get to the page. This causes a Postback and during this postback I go into the Page_Init event. Here I need the value they selected.

I have spent all day trying to figure out how I can access this control's value in the Page_Init.

I tried this and it is always null:

```
string productId = Request.Form[ddlProduct.UniqueID];
```

Comment: can you add some more code?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
      string controlName = page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controlName))
       {
          control = page.FindControl(controlName);
       }
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean. How does this get my ddlProduct's value when ddlProduct is never specified anywhere.